# Ionic 4 - how to dynamically add component to page?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have my component ready to use this way in HTML:

```
<pop-product></pop-product>
```

But I need to add it dynamically in a function, something like:

```
async openPopProduct(){
  // append component to html body
  // add data into it
}

async closePopProduct(){
  // remove component from html
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options is using  [*ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf).

**example.html**

```
<pop-product *ngIf="showComponent"></pop-product>
```

**example.ts**

```
showComponent: boolean = false;

async openPopProduct(){
  this.showComponent = true;
  // add data into it
}

async closePopProduct(){
  // remove component from HTML
  this.showComponent = false;
}
```